# Touch on multiple ActivityViews in Android11

Tags: android, android-activity, touch-event, android-virtualdisplay

how can i use multiple ActivityViews correctly in Android11?

I already created a working sample in P+Q. But in R touch stopped working. The activities are displayed well but only the highest view reacts on touch. All other activies do not respond. If i reorder the views during runtime, the new highest activity becomes interactable. The other views will again not respond.

After a lot of testing i saw, that those ActivityViews which are not interactable, will receive touch events if i add a corresponding listerner inside the hosting app. Strange is that the view which is working well, will not get any event. I assume that the touch is redirected through the virtual display to the hosted activity directly. But i dont have a proof.

How can i make all hosted activities interactable? Since i have system access, i am fine with accessing hidden APIs. Unfortunately i cannot find which change in R causes the issue. So at least hints where to search would be helpful because i am running out of ideas.

Comment: i created a bug to google and it seems that its indeed an issue on aosp side: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171334506